# Как проверить относительный или абсолютный путь php?

Tags: php, пути

Имеется массив путей к картинкам. Одни пути абсолютные другие относительные.
Как можно выбрать только абсолютные? С `www` и `http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так пути или урлы? Если урлы то проверяйте что это урл, самое простое регуляркой, но это долго, можно действительно смотреть наличие http

есть это именно пути, то у абсолютного в начале идет /

Answer (score 1):

is_file, is_dir, realpath, stat - эти функции смотрите